# android device management in .net/c#

Tags: c#, java, android, .net, mobile

Can I use .NET instead of Java to apply enterprise policies on an android device?

I found "AndroidLib - .NET Android Device Communication and Management Library", but it seems to be lower-level stuff, not an enterprise policies management library. Moreover, it's a wrapper over Java, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Q: Can you program for Android in a .Net language?  A: Yes, but I'd advise using Java - more power, less overhead.  Q: But what exactly are you trying to do here?  Could you give a couple of examples of "enterprise policies"?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to implement Mobile Device Management like the ability to configure corporate profiles on multiple devices. I.e. all employees get the same environment with email/calendar settings in their phones. Or, when the employee leaves the company, the admin remotely wipes all the corporate data.